# Dynamic way to pass url pamars in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/asas/asasa'}).success(function(data) {        
        $scope.website = data.websites;
        $scope.topoffer = data.coupons;

        $scope.webcall = function () {      
            $http({method: 'GET',url: '/asas/asas?websiteId='+data.website.websiteId}).success(function(data) {
                $scope.onlinedata = data.coupons;                      
            });        

        };
    });
```

My html file-

```
<div class="check_box"  ng-repeat="web in topoffer">                                                    
                                                 <label ng-click="webcall()"for="{{web}}"><input type="checkbox" id="{{web.websiteId}}" />{{web.websitename}}</label>                                                   
                                            </div>
```

when some click on label need to pass that id in my onclick function url . I am using angular js 1.2.17

my json file

```
"websites":[{
 "websiteName":"Flipkart",
 "websiteId":"1",
  },
  {
 "websiteName":"asas",
 "websiteId":"5",
  }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you pass the `web` object with the call in `ng-click` ? e.g.:

```
<div class="check_box" ng-repeat="web in topoffer">                                                    
     <label ng-click="webcall(web)"for="{{web}}"><input type="checkbox" id="{{web.websiteId}}" />{{web.websitename}}</label>                                                   
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
    $scope.webcall = function(web) {
        $http({method: 'GET',url: '/asas/asas?websiteId='+web.websiteId}).success(function(data) {
            $scope.onlinedata = data.coupons;                      
        });        
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$http({method: 'GET',url: '/asas/asas', params: { websiteId:data.website.websiteId })
```

Comment: My api url give json out put.It show error websiteId undefined

Comment: I can't help you there

Comment: ok,i try to pass id base on input id means my html output like <label ng-click="webcall()" class="ng-binding"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter[web]" id="1" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">asasa</label> <label ng-click="webcall()" class="ng-binding"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter[web]" id="2" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">asasa</label> so when some one click first label then need to pass id 1 and when click 2nd label need to pass id 2